# jQuery show div in PHP While loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of problems trying to show an information in a div tag using jQuery inside the PHP while loop.

My code looks like this:

```
$i=1;
    while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($packs)) 
        {
$pricepack = $price * $pack['refcount'];
$pricepack = number_format($pricepack,2);

if($users > $pack['refcount'] ) {
$contents .= "

  <a class='refbutton' style='text-decoration:none;' onclick=\"document.rent.refs.value='{$pack['refcount']}';document.rent.submit(); return false;\" >{$pack['refcount']}</a>

<div id='refinfo' style='display:none;'>

<span style='font-size:18pt;font-weight:bold;' id='refprice'></span><br />
<span style='color:#D01F1E;'>You don't have enough funds for this package.</span>
  </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.refbutton').hover(
function() {                         
  $('#refinfo').show();
   $('#refprice').text(\"$\"+\"$pricepack\");

  },
function() {
  $('#refinfo').hide()
   }
  );
});

</script>


";
   $i++;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the code is generating a `div` next to each anchor element. This will cause this when the mouse hovers:

[image: Problem]

What I am trying to obtain is this on every button hover:

[image: Correct solution]

As you can see in the second picture, there isn't any design errors or mix-ups. How can I obtain this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this inside your loop? $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('.refbutton').hover(
                       function() {                         
                          $('#refinfo').show();
                          $('#refprice').text(\"$\"+\"$pricepack\");

                       },
                       function() {
                          $('#refinfo').hide()
                       }
                    );
                });

Comment: Try `$("#refinfo").html("<span style='color:#D01F1E;'>You don't have enough funds for this package.</span>");` below your `$('#refprice').text(\"$\"+\"$pricepack\");` - *made a typo in earlier comment.*

Comment: @oliverbj - have you tried what I placed as a comment above?

Comment: @Copenhagen It's because each button represent a referral package (option), and therefore the message that the jQuery is printing must be different.

Comment: @Fred Yes, but that didn't work. It doesn't change anything, as the div #refinfo is the problem when it is being printed out inside the anchor tags...

Comment: @oliverbj Hm, theoretically that should've worked. What is the ID or CLASS you're using to produce `3, 10, 20, 50` as well as the `$37.50`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start by cleaning up your code. You only need one refinfo div, and only one javascript block. The only thing in your loop should be the refbutton, and that tag should contain all the values needed for the javscript hover and click events to do their business. Look into HTML5 custom data attributes http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Something more like this should work and provide a sounder basis on which to debug layout issues if any remain.

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($packs)) {
    $pricepack = $price * $pack['refcount'];
    $pricepack = number_format($pricepack,2);

    if($users > $pack['refcount'] ) {
        $contents .= "
        <a class=\"refbutton\" data-pricepack=\"{$pricepack}\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\" >{$pack['refcount']}</a>";
        $i++;
    }
}  
?>

<div id="refinfo" style="display:none;">
    <span style="font-size:18pt;font-weight:bold;" id="refprice"></span><br />
    <span style="color:#D01F1E;">You don't have enough funds for this package.</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.refbutton')
            .bind('mouseover',function(event) {
                $('#refinfo').show();
                $('#refprice').text($(this).data("pricepack"));
            })
            .bind('click',function(event) {
                document.rent.refs.value=$(this).text();
            })
            .bind('mouseout', function(event){
                $('#refinfo').hide();
            })
        ;
    });
</script>
```